# MS UI automation - Custom DataGrid

Tags: wpf, user-interface, ui-automation

currently i am working on automating one of my .net based application using WPF(in Excel vba).UI spy is not recognizing one of the control(Grid) as an object.Is there any way to select an item from Grid which is not identified by UI spy.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try Snoop for identifying the UI controls. [This](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) is the codeplex link for downloading it.

Snoop has worked for me in a lot of cases where UI Spy had given up.